# Photoshop CC: Direct selection tool shortcut

Tags: photoshop

just a quick question about the **direct selection tool** in Photoshop:

Is there a shortcut to switch the settings I've highlighted? (*See image*)

I find myself clicking there manualy way too often.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cmd of course temporarily gives you the move tool.

Cmd + Mouse right click will bring up a context menu where you can select a layer.

Cmd + Alt + Shift + Mouse right click will select or deselect the clicked layer.

Cmd + Alt + Mouse left click and drag will copy / move the selected layer

Cmd + Alt + Arrow key will copy / move the selected layer 1px to the direction of your choosing

Cmd + Alt + Shift Arrow key will copy / move the selected layer 10px to the direction of your choosing.

Comment: If you are on Windows just replace Cmd with Ctrl